# Disable sound system

Tags: android, button, media-player, system-sounds

I'm developing an app with sounds and I play the sounds with buttons, but my problem is when you click on a button to play sound also includes the sound of system. how can I turn off the system sound automatically when you start my application? thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "sound of system"? Are you talking about the touch sounds?

Comment: yes this sound, when touch a button

Comment: I have to call all the buttons with that method?